# Remove or Hide New task/New Event button from Activity List View

Tags: page-layout, standard-objects, related-list, activities, button

I need to remove or hide New task/New Event button from the standard Activity List View. I want to show users the list view but do not want any user to create a Task/Event from that view.
Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to go and edit the page layout for the object you want to do this for.  Find the Open Activities and Activity History related lists.  Click on the Wrench Icon, and go to the Buttons section.  There are checkboxes for all the buttons.  Just uncheck the buttons you do not want to show.

[image]

[image]

> EDIT

Thanks to @BarCotter, you also need to update the List View.  this can be done by navigating to

**Setup > Customize > Activities > Activity Search Layouts > Click Edit on Activities List View**

Comment: You will also need to remove the buttons from the Activity List View via **Setup** > **Customize** > **Activities** > **Activity Search Layouts** > Click **Edit** on **Activities List View**

Comment: Good point, did not read the question closely enough and missed the list view part.  Updated the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja: Thanks a ton, this is what I was looking for.